# Android user location request

Tags: android, gps, location

I am developing an application that is based on GPS/user location.
There is one main activity I called MainController that is managin fragments (replacing them) and also manages bottom tabs (activating selected tab & deactivating others).
In one FragmentList class, I need to sort objects by distance from user and pass them into ArrayAdapter. All I need is now user location, but the most important question is how to request user location, that after navigating to another fragment I could be able to update this location and when it is needed, pass it into fragment (or request from fragment).
Do I need to use Service ? Is there other way to achieve this ? I thought about Application object, but I don't know if it really can request user locations ?

Comment: I think `Service` is the best approach. There's *plenty* of online tutorials on how to achieve it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call [Location API's](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) in `MainController`

As for communicating with Fragments, [the documentation is pretty clear](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) on how to do it